# Div height animation causes divs to change alignment in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, height

I'm trying to animate the height of 5 divs on the click of a button. Although these divs do increase in size the animation causes the divs to align at the Top rather than from the bottom. If that makes any sense. **I would actually prefer it to animate while coming down from the top (so aligned from the top)** but even if its the other way around, this animation just completes itself then changes the divs locations.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#f").css("display", "inline");
  $(".css").css("display", "inline");
  $(".html").css("display", "inline");
  $(".jQuery").css("display", "inline");
  $(".premiere").css("display", "inline");
  $(".photoshop").css("display", "inline");
  $(".css").animate({height:'300'}, 600);
  $(".html").animate({height:'300'}, 600);
  $(".jQuery").animate({height:'125'}, 600);
  $(".premiere").animate({height:'250'}, 600);
  $(".photoshop").animate({height:'325'}, 600);
});
```

```css
p{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#f, .css, .html, .jQuery, .premiere, .photoshop{
  height: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

.css{ background-color: blue }

.html{ background-color: red }

.jQuery{ background-color: orange }

.premiere{ background-color: purple }

.photoshop{ background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Go</button>
<div></div>
<div class="f">
  <div class="html"><p>HTML</p></div>
  <div class="css"><p>CSS</p></div>
  <div class="jQuery"><p>jQuery</p></div>
  <div class="premiere"><p>Premiere</p></div>
  <div class="photoshop"><p>Photoshop</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: bottom` to `.jQuery`, `.html`, `.premiere`, `.photoshop` and `.css`.

### Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wocb0mbv/7/)

Comment: Whoops, can't believe I missed that. Thanks to you good sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, for the version animating from the top down, as you would prefer it (if I understood you correct):

I also added a common class to all the bars and updated your JS and CSS a bit, to make your code a little less redundant

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znxue2wg/**

---

**JS, CSS, HTML:**

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".bar").css("display", "inline");
  $(".bar.html").animate({height:'300'}, 600);
  $(".bar.css").animate({height:'300'}, 600);
  $(".bar.jQuery").animate({height:'125'}, 600);
  $(".bar.premiere").animate({height:'250'}, 600);
  $(".bar.photoshop").animate({height:'325'}, 600);
});
```

```css
.bar {
  display: none;
  height: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.bar.html {background-color: red;}
.bar.css {background-color: blue;}
.bar.jQuery {background-color: orange;}
.bar.premiere {background-color: purple;}
.bar.photoshop {background-color: yellow;}

.bar p {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Go</button>
<div>
  <div class="bar html"><p>HTML</p></div>
  <div class="bar css"><p>CSS</p></div>
  <div class="bar jQuery"><p>jQuery</p></div>
  <div class="bar premiere"><p>Premiere</p></div>
  <div class="bar photoshop"><p>Photoshop</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I already solved my problem but thank you for making the code a little less redundant :)